# Linear Algebra counter example with orthonormal basis and isometries

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove or give a counterexample: if $S \in \mathcal{L}(V)$ and there exists an ortho- normalbasis $e_{1},...,e_{n} $ of V such that $||Se_{j}|| = 1$ for each $e_{j}$, then S is an isometry

I saw this question in my textbook while self studying (Axler 7.C.13) and I saw a solution online which stated that S was not invertible which therefore means its not an isometry by a theorem but I was wondering why its not invertible. Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The conditions given about $S$ in your questions do not rule out invertibility.  After all $S = I$ will satisfy those conditions.

But the statement is false for $n \geq 2$.  Here is a counterexample.  Define $S$ to map every basis vector $e_{j}$ to the same vector $e_{1}$.  Then $S$ has a non-trivial kernel (for example, this kernel contains the nonzero vector $e_{1}-e_{2}$), hence fails to be invertible, hence fails to be an isometry.